# How to get Xpath Value in Hive

Tags: hive

I wanted to get the value of Hindi & English as an arry from the below xml using XPATH in Hive.

```
<employees>
    <employee>
        <name>Ranjith</name>
        <language emp:langCode="HI">Hindi</language>
        <city emp:country="india">Delhi</city>
    <employee>
    <employee>
        <name>John</name>
        <language emp:langCode="EN">English</language>
        <city emp:country="america">Sunnyvale</city>
    <employee>  
</employees>
```

Can anyone help??

I have tried few options, but not works.

Answer (score 0):

Generic xpath would be:

```
      /employees/employee/language
```

But your xml has some errors in it. Here is the updated xml that works:

```
<employees>
    <employee>
        <name>Ranjith</name>
        <language langCode="HI">Hindi</language>
        <city country="india">Delhi</city>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <name>John</name>
        <language langCode="EN">English</language>
        <city country="america">Sunnyvale</city>
    </employee>  
</employees>
```

And here is the result using the shown xpath

```
Element='<language langCode="HI">Hindi</language>'
Element='<language langCode="EN">English</language>'
```